# Summing values in dictionaries within class instances

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

I want to sum all the values in all the below instances. 
Is there a way to sum all values in the instances together?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, neighbour):
        self.neighbour = {}
        self.name = name
        self.neighbour = dict(neighbour)

N1 = Node('N1', {'N7': 15, 'N6': 5, 'N5': 20, 'N4': 20, 'N2': 10})
N2 = Node('N2', {'N4': 10, 'N3': 5})
N3 .... N10
```

EDIT, tried to make it clearer

Comment: Yes, store your instances in a list. Whenever you see yourself creating variables `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`, stop what you're doing and use a list instead.

Comment: What are the numbers that you are referring to? The values of each `neighbour` dictionary?

Comment: @Aran-Fey While I agree, I'm not sure that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: yes, the numbers inside the neighbors dictionary

Comment: Ok, I guess the question is unclear. What should be summed up, and what's the expected result?

Comment: Define "quick". What have you tried that isn't quick enough?

Comment: `[sum(n.neighbour.values()) for n in list_of_nodes]`? (`list_of_nodes` being `[N1, N2, ... , N10]`)

Comment: i did not think about storing the instances in a list and summed it one by one ( - not the quick way :))
figured it out now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want as your desired output. Below are 3 interpretations of your problem.

I use a dictionary to store your class instances, as this is the recommended way to store a variable number of variables.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, neighbour={}):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbour = dict(neighbour)

N = {1: Node('N1', {'N7': 15, 'N6': 5, 'N5': 20, 'N4': 20, 'N2': 10}),
     2: Node('N2', {'N4': 10, 'N3': 5}),
     3: Node('N3', {'N5': 20, 'N2': 15, 'N4': 5})}

### sum by node ###

sum_by_node = {k: sum(v.neighbour.values()) for k, v in N.items()}
# {1: 70, 2: 15, 3: 40}

### sum across nodes by key ###

keys = set().union(*(v.neighbour for v in N.values()))
sum_by_key = {k: sum(v.neighbour.get(k, 0) for v in N.values()) for k in keys}
# {'N2': 25, 'N3': 5, 'N4': 35, 'N5': 40, 'N6': 5, 'N7': 15}

### sum across nodes and across keys ###

sum_all = sum(sum(v.neighbour.values()) for v in N.values())
# 125
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `__add__` method of your `Node` class, you can use the built-in: `sum()`.

```
@property
def _total(self): #helper property to get sum of single node
    return sum(self.neighbor.values())

def __add__(self, other):
    if type(other) == self.__class__: #first two elements taken with `sum()` will be
                                      # of type: <Node>
        return self._total + other._total
    elif type(other) == int:  #subsequent additions (because sum() works like reduce())
                              # will add running total with next node
        return self._total + other
    else:  #don't bother trying to handle all types..
        raise TypeError("can't add {} with {}".format(self.__class__, other.__class__))
```

Then to get the total sum: `sum([N1, N2, N3, ...N10])`